# Setting Row Level Security for multiple of values

Tags: powerbi, dax, row-level-security

I am trying to set a row-level security on Power BI where a user can only access data based on the country they are tied to. Also, they can access other user's data, ONLY if they are both tied to the same country. A user can be tied to more than one country. Sample data is shown below.

For example, if user A access the Power BI report, they can only see data for US, Canada, Italy, and Germany. Also, can access other user's data, if their countries are tied with the same country as user A.

[image]

I have tried this DAX but it doesn't work. Maybe I have to use something similar to an IN operator?

```
[Country] = CALCULATE( VALUES([Country]) , [User] = username() )
```

Please let me know if this is possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible.

But first you should have a dictionary with user email. So either replace your User column with User_Email or have it related in other table. Then set up a role and add this:

```
[User_Email] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the help! Doing it this way, the user can only see the countries they are tied to. I was seeing if it is possible if the user can see other users that are tied to the same country they are tied to.

For example, user A can see that user F is part of the US as well.

Comment: Yes, replace A with user adam@email in your sample data. Replace B with barbara@email and so on. Both Adam and Barbara may have access to US, though Adam may have access to Canada while Barbara not.

Comment: Makes sense. If I want to view all rows that has countries tied to me, regardless of who the user is, how would I do that? Basically, view all countries where [User] = USERPRINCIPALNAME(). How would I do that for Row Level Security?

Comment: Define a role like 'AllCountries' and do not define any restriction to that role. Add your User to this role. General advice for you is to experiment with roles. You may for example define roles like 'Europe' and add users to that role.